# Python: Scipy's curve_fit only chooses lowest bound as fit parameter

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a Planck distribution to some data, but the `curve_fit` function in scipy always just chooses the lowest bound as the fit parameter (in this case 0.7, but it should converge to 1). No matter where I set the bounds or `p0` it never converges towards the data, but always just to the lower bound, see picture below.

I read in some forums that rescaling the data can help, but that didn't work either.

Does someone have an idea what the problem might be?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rng


# Planck Distribution
def f(x, t):
    h = 6.6*10**-34
    c = 3*10**8
    k_b = 1.4*10**-23
    nm = 10**-9
    return 10**32*2*h*c**2/(x**5)/(np.exp(h*c/x/nm/k_b/9000/t)-1)


# Data to fit with some randomness
x = []
for i in range(1, 1500, 10):
    x.append(i)

y = []
for e in x:
    y.append(f(e, 1) + rng.randint(-2, 2))


# Fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=1, bounds=(0.7, 1.3))
print('parameter:', popt[0])


# Plot data and fit
y_fit = []
for e in x:
    y_fit.append(f(e, popt[0]))

plt.plot(x, y, 'x')
plt.plot(x, y_fit)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: I ran your code without any alteration and got `parameter: 0.996`.

Comment: Thanks. That was actually really helpful. I ran it through the console instead of Spyder and now it's suddenly working...!? Might I ask what Editor / Enviroment you are using?

Comment: I ran it in JupyterLab

Comment: I've run your code and got: ```x.py:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 10**32*2*h*c**2/(x**5)/(np.exp(h*c/x/nm/k_b/9000/t)-1)
parameter: 0.997707060601484
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I guess the exponential function is leading to some overflows that my Spyder does weird things with. I now got it working with the real data set too instead of my 'fake' random data.